# Is there a way to access class attribute through a decorator?

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator, python-decorators

I'm practicing with decorators on a simple bank account class. And I'm trying to display the "self.balance" through the decorator. However, because of scope I'm getting a 'NameError'. Is there any way around this?

```
def statement(f):
    def helper(*args):
        f(*args)
        print(f"{f.__name__} of {args[1]} completed. \nYour new balance is {self.balance}")
    return helper

class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        with open('balance.txt', 'r') as file:
            self.balance = float(file.read())

    @statement
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount

    @statement
    def withdrawal(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
```

Comment: Replace `self` with `args[0]`.

Comment: "local class variable" seems a confusing way to refer to what you're trying to access here.  It is an attribute of the class, and also it is being referenced in the local scope of the `deposit` and `withdrawal` functions.  `args[0]` within your decorator will get the first function argument passed, i.e. the instance of the class, aka `self`

Comment: Thank you. replacing self with args[0] did it. cheers.